# Java application with multiple JFrames does not terminate when all JFrames are closed

Tags: java, swing, jframe, exit

I'm creating a standalone data management program for a competition (so I won't post all the code, only relevant stuff)--however, I am testing it in Eclipse Neon at the moment because it's not done. Also, I used WindowBuilder, if that matters (I don't think it should.)

I have one JFrame (call it "welcome") that opens when the application is first launched. In "welcome", I have a JButton that opens a different JFrame (call it "emp") and closes "welcome" (via frame.dispose().) If I exit "welcome" (with the default upper-right-corner X), then the program terminates. However, if I click on the Jbutton to open "emp" and then close "emp" in the same manner, the program does not terminate. My question is  **how to make the program terminate when "emp" is exited.**

My code for the first JFrame ("welcome"):

```
public class Welcome extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JFrame frame;

    // Launch the application.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Welcome window = new Welcome();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Create the application.
    public Welcome() {
        initialize();
        frame.pack();
    }

    //Variable declaration.
    //A bunch of variables that aren't important
    //End variable declaration.

    // Initialize the contents of the frame.
    private void initialize() {
        //TODO comment this out better
        //Create the JFrame and set all of its stuff.
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(lightGrey);
        frame.setIconImage(logo.getImage());
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        SpringLayout springLayout = new SpringLayout();
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(springLayout);     

        //Add a bunch of components that also aren't important
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("employees")) {
            frame.dispose();
            Employees emp  = new Employees();
            emp.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

And my code for the second JFrame ("emp"):

```
public class Employees extends JFrame {

    private JFrame frame2;

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public Employees() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame2 = new JFrame();
        frame2.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

They're both set to EXIT_ON_CLOSE, but it only works if I exit "welcome", not "emp". If anyone has any ideas/solutions, I'm all ears!

Comment: You are extending `JFrame` and have a `JFrame` in the same class... Why? That is most likely your problem. You are doing it to the wrong `JFrame`... All you would need is this for any `JFrame` to exit your program `frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`

Comment: [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636)

Comment: @3kings Aha, got it, thanks so much! I had no idea you weren't supposed to extend JFrame and create a JFrame in the same program (I just started using swing like two days ago... lol)

Comment: @Shannon No problem. Goodluck